# How to give NSWindow a particular background color

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder

I am writing a cocoa application which has a NSWindow. I want to change the background color of the window to a specific color. But the window properties in the inspector only provide "Textured Window" alternative. How can I make the color of the window as desired?

Answer (score 28):

Try calling the instance method setBackgroundColor: with a color on your window instance.  What's in a name.. ;)

Like this:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Option 1
    [self.window setBackgroundColor: NSColor.whiteColor];
    // Option 2 - using dot syntax
    self.window.backgroundColor = NSColor.whiteColor;
}
```

Comment: Has there been a major update since this answer? `window` is undefined and when I actually get the window reference, `backgroundColor` and `setBackgroundColor` do nothing.

Comment: Agreed. This would work in UIKit (with `UIColor`), but not AppKit.

Comment: @Jeff This code must be part of a custom NSWindowController subclass and you'd better put in into awakeFromNib so it is called whenever your window is loaded form a Nib file.

Comment: @Zev It works just fine with AppKit, have been using this code already over 2 years ago. But see answer of Arclite, it will only work if then window has been configured to be textured.

Comment: `self.window` is not available while using storyboards.

Answer (score 16):

The simplest way to change window background is to set it directly in your .xib file.

No code at all:

1. Select your window (NSWindow class should appear in Class field)
2. Click [+] button under the User Defined Runtime Attributes
3. Type "backgroundColor" and select Color

[image: Window Properties in XCode]

Comment: It works on 10.10, just captured a video special for @SpaceDog: [http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I0AHPxvNlp8](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I0AHPxvNlp8)

Comment: I've found that for some reason some or all user defined runtime attributes do not work on the NSWindow instance in the generated storyboard, with 10.10 and XCode 6.4. I ran into it with titlebarAppearsTransparent first, and just confirmed the same behaviour with backgroundColor. Very annoying to have to go back to subclassing just for configuration.

Answer (score 5):

As long as you only want to change the background color of the content area, not the frame and toolbar, you don't need to subclass `NSWindow`. What you do need to do is subclass `NSView` and make your custom view draw your desired color, then set an instance of that class as the window's content view.

Alternatively, you may be able to get away with setting a borderless `NSImageView` or `NSColorWell` as the content view, but I'm not sure that Apple means for those to have subviews. If not, you'd have to leave your window empty.

That said, you should be *really* sure that a custom background color is appropriate. Almost always, it's not, and you should stick with the Aqua or HUD appearance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to subclass NSWindow in order to change the background and then override the implementation for

```
- (id)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect
                styleMask:(NSUInteger)styleMask
                  backing:(NSBackingStoreType)bufferingType
                    defer:(BOOL)flag
```

As an example see Mat Gemmell's HUDWindow: http://mattgemmell.com/2006/03/12/hudwindow